JSON file not found when using custom dataset in detectron2
I am trying to train a model in detectron2 with a custom dataset I annotated myself in CVAT.
I downloaded the annotation in COCO JSON format. However, when following the tutorial from detectron2 to upload custom COCO format datasets I get the error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './content/resectionline/train/instances.json'


This is the last code I tried in Google Colab:
from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
register_coco_instances("resectionline_train", {}, "instances.json", "content/resectionline/train")
register_coco_instances("resectionline_val", {}, "instances.json", "content/resectionline/val")

from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
register_coco_instances("resectionline", {}, "./content/resectionline/train/instances.json", "./content/resectionline/train/")

dataset_dicts = DatasetCatalog.get("resectionline")

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-4aea893e4172> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dataset_dicts = DatasetCatalog.get("resectionline")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycocotools/coco.py in __init__(self, annotation_file)
     79             print('loading annotations into memory...')
     80             tic = time.time()
---> 81             with open(annotation_file, 'r') as f:
     82                 dataset = json.load(f)
     83             assert type(dataset)==dict, 'annotation file format {} not supported'.format(type(dataset))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './content/resectionline/train/instances.json'


I tried to do it with an example dataset I found online and the same code worked. So I know it is a problem with my JSON file.
I downloaded it in COCO format.
I did the folder structure the same as them.
I also tried this: Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
Nothing worked.
Btw, the path the error shows is correct and the file is there.

Solved. When using detectron2 with the COCO dataset, you need to have a specific folder arrangement:
datasets
- dataset_name
 - annotations
 - train 
 - val
 - test

